# How to add taxonomies to users then query users to be displayed on a listing grid using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created user taxonomies using this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw0MeLMtZzs.  It worked but I am looking to be able to query users on the front-end to be displayed on a listing grid using Wordpress.  I want to be able to be on a specific page "Artist" page, and when on that page I want a listing grid to display the users who are "Artists".

Any tips or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried any dynamic plugin yet?

This would fasten up the process of query custom data based on User/Post/Page/Relation/Taxonomies IDs, please take a look at the following list of plugins:

JetEngine https://crocoblock.com/plugins/jetengine/

Dynamic.ooo https://www.dynamic.ooo/

ACF https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/